# I heard Mary sang a good song?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> 1. I heard Mary sing a good song.
> 2. I heard Mary sang a good song.

Comment: (1) You heard the song yourself. (2) Someone else told you about it. (_Heard that_ could be used to make the meaning clearer.)

Comment: To whoever can answer: shouldn't it be "sing**s**" or sing**ing**" in the first sentence? I would favor "singing", but "sings" makes sense too, with different meaning. Plain "sing" sounds incorrect to me, at least until I understand the sentence structure better.

Answer (score 2):

The first has the base form *sing*, so the clause *Mary sing a good song* is an infinitive clause. This means that *hear* must have its primary meaning of "physically hear the sound of something happening". *Singing* would also be possible there, with the same meaning.

The second has an inflected (finite) verb form, so the clause *Mary sang a good song* cannot be an infinitive clause, and must be a "that" clause with "that" omitted. The meaning of *hear that* is different: it means "come to know, by hearing or reading something that somebody said or wrote".